# How to select data from table with two condition

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select data from table with two condition with union or if any for table

```
    name       special

    Deepak         s
    mukesh         v
    dinesh         s
    girgesh        v
    Deepak         s
    mukesh         v
    dinesh         s
    girgesh        v
    Deepak         s
    mukesh         v
    dinesh         s
    girgesh        v
```

query for fetching data...

```
SELECT NAME FROM  student WHERE special = "s" LIMIT 2
UNION 
SELECT NAME FROM student WHERE special = "v"  LIMIT 2
```

but its gives only first condition before union...
how to get two different condition data from single table

Comment: SELECT NAME FROM  student WHERE special = "s" OR special = "v"  LIMIT 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [MySQL's documentation on UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT

---

So you'd want to use:

```
(SELECT NAME FROM  student WHERE special = "s" LIMIT 2)
UNION 
(SELECT NAME FROM student WHERE special = "v"  LIMIT 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Burned Buffen in comments:

```
SELECT NAME FROM  student WHERE special = "s" or special = "v" LIMIT 2
```